# Trying to apply formula to each column in R, how to feed data to formula?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

So I'm trying to apply an exponential smoothing model to each column in a data frame called 'cities'. I have used apply to identify the data frame, go by columns, and I thought to run the model. However, when I try to do so, it tells me that I need to specify data for the exponential smoothing model...I thought I already had by putting it in the apply loop.

```
apply(x=cities,2,FUN=HoltWinters(x=x,gamma=FALSE))
```

Also, eventually I'd like to predict the next 4 periods using the HW model developed using forecast.predict. Do I need to use a different loop or can I combine it all in this one?

Comment: Try `apply(x=cities,2,FUN=function(x){HoltWinters(x=x,gamma=FALSE))})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FUN` takes a `function`, but you're trying to give it the output of a function.
Try this:

```
apply(cities, 2, FUN=function(x) HoltWinters(x=x,gamma=FALSE))
```

Comment: Or, more succinctly: `apply(cities, 2, HoltWinters, gamma=FALSE)`.

Comment: both worked perfectly! Is there a way to add the forecast.HoltWinters within the apply?

Comment: `FUN` can be whatever custom function you want